Intermediate step of working with a basic partial derivative question
What’s the most appropriate intermediate step for the partial derivative of f wrt x where
$$f(x,y) = \sqrt((x+7)² + (y-3)² + 5) $$
Usually I’d got straight from $f(x,y) = \sqrt((x+7)² + (y-3)² + 5) $ to $f_x= \frac{2(x+7)}{2\sqrt((x+7)^2 + (y-3)^2 +5)}$ using the chain rule “mentally”. However for this specific exercise I need to clearly show every step.
I kind of feel like a substitution would be overkill, I was thinking something alone the lines of $f_x = \frac{d((x+7)²)}{dx} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial (x+7)²}$ or $f_x = \frac{\partial ((x+7)²+ (y-3)² + 5)}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{df}{d((x+7)² + (x-3)² +5)}$ but returning to the basics is surprisingly confusing. I would really appreciate some help because everything I write seems wrong.


I kind of feel like a substitution would be overkill,

If you need to show steps, then err on the side of showing the obvious.
The first thing you do 'mentally' is take care of the square root, so start with that.
$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} &= \dfrac{\partial\sqrt{(x+7)^2 + (y-3)^2 + 5}}{\partial x}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathrm d\sqrt u}{\mathrm d u}\cdot\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\hspace{-10ex}{u:={(x+7)^2 + (y-3)^2 + 5}} \\[2ex]&=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(x+7)^2 + (y-3)^2 + 5}}\cdot\dfrac{\partial ({(x+7)^2 + (y-3)^2 + 5})}{\partial x} \\[2ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$
